# Delay entry of orders for a SMA trend indicator - Trading View, Pine Script v5

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have very simple SMA based strategy which is as follows:

```
//@version=5

//Initialization
strategy(title='SMA', shorttitle='SMA', overlay=true, initial_capital=100, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

//Inputs
src = input(close)
len = input(20, title='SMA Length')
smoothening = input.int(2, minval=1, maxval=10, title='1 = No Smoothing')

//Indicator
sma = ta.sma(src, len)
out = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, sma)

//Strategy
ma_up = out >= out[smoothening]
ma_down = out < out[smoothening]

//Plot
col = ma_up ? color.lime : ma_down ? color.red : color.aqua 
plot(out, title='Multi-Timeframe Moving Avg', style=plot.style_line, linewidth=4, color=col)

//Backtest
if ma_up
    strategy.close('S', comment = "EXIT_SHORT")
    strategy.entry('L', strategy.long, comment = "ENTER_LONG")
if ma_down
    strategy.close('L', comment = "EXIT_LONG")
    strategy.entry('S', strategy.short, comment = "ENTER_SHORT")
```

Now after implementing this strategy, I am getting quite an interesting result where the plotline seems to be correct but the entry and exits of the trades are occurring after a slight delay

[image]

That is, if we were to remove the bars then the offset becomes clearer

[image]

However, the ideal should be entries and exits at the point at which the plotline changes color like in the following picture

[image]

How can I eliminate this delay between the plotline transitions and the trade entries/exits so that they can be in sync? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add process_orders_on_close=true in the strategy function

```
strategy(title='SMA', shorttitle='SMA', overlay=true, initial_capital=100, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, process_orders_on_close=true)
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helped improve my results 
I was also wondering; in the past I noticed that Trading View was changing the prices for the entries and exits of my trades, that is, when an alert was issued the entry price was 17.125 but after some time it changed to 16.995. Any idea on why this was happening?

Comment: could be a repaint issue due to how the strategy logic is built
With entries not based on candle close, you'll often get discrepancies between the infos in the alerts AND the historical infos you'll see later
Does that make sense?

Comment: Yup, it makes perfect sense, and you're spot as it was due to repainting and entries not based on candle close. Thank you for confirming this, it really helped!